# SharePoint PeoplePicker - Prevent user deleting value

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a form with a PeoplePicker control on it that I do not want the user to be able to edit.

Normally in situations like these setting the controls `Enabled` property to `false` would suffice, however I'm having issues with the value being cleared on postback (the form is very customised with numerous sub-sections that interact with each other).

I've tried the following:

`peoplePicker.EnableBrowse = false;
peoplePicker.AllowTypeIn = false;`

This solves nearly all my problems, the user cannot enter any values, the value is not cleared on postback, HOWEVER, the user is able to delete the current value.

How can I completely prevent the user from editing the controls value without setting `Enabled` to `false`?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

EDIT: Forgot to mention this needs to be done server side, there's a lot of logic on the form revolving around the users AD group and their sharepoint permissions so javascript isn't really an option.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint people picker is basically a div with `contenteditable` property. If you can inject javascript, here is the solution:

http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2012/03/05/quick-tip-5/

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned JS isn't really usable as the form has a lot of logic around which AD group the user belongs to and what SP permissions he has.  This would be a lot more work in JS than if I could do this server side.

Answer (score 1):

You could prevent users from deleting value by pressing event of `Backspace` and `Delete` keys using JavaScript/jQuery solution.

### Solution

Along with specifying `EnableBrowse` and `AllowTypeIn` properties, add the following script on the page where `PeopleEditor` control resides:

```
$("body").on("keydown", "span", function(e) {   
  if ( (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46)  && e.target.id.indexOf("userPicker_upLevelDiv") > -1) 
     e.preventDefault(); 
  });
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned JS isn't really usable as the form has a lot of logic around which AD group the user belongs to and what SP permissions he has.  This would be a lot more work in JS than if I could do this server side.

Comment: Otherwise I would do something similar, yes, thank you.